# python - how can I select a class and get the number of another class with whitespace between them using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Problem: automate answer to a website that has new messages.

Breakdown:

1. Login into the website DONE
2. Get to the page where is the messages DONE
3. Find new messages class NOT DONE
4. Get the number of the new message that appear on url NOT DONE YET

I'm using Selenium to automate this process in Python 2.5

**Can't select classes with whitespace in them**

I was looking through the webite source and I noticed every time there is a new message a new class pop up class: `notifycircle new fnormal abs nowrap br3 cfff lheight16`. 
[Showing the red icon that we have new message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4bBE.png)

[The class that appear showing that there is a new message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDZfm.png)

As you can see there is white space between them and I can't use `find_element_by_class_name` from Selenium library. I know this is a classic `I can't select classes that has white space between them - Python Selenium`. I have tried using `find_element_by_css_selector` without luck either.

```
...
browser.get("websitehere")
#if found certain class I will proced to the final goal
if browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".notifycircle.new.fnormal.abs.nowrap.br3.cfff.lheight16"):
    print "Found element"
```

**Select the number of the new message**

As you can see in image 2: `id_answer_row_####` means the number of the message. I would like to grab that message number. How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: There is no such thing as "classes with whitespace in them"! It is a **space-separated list** of class names. You can used `find_element_by_class_name` and pass any **one** of the classes from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to examine that span element?  The tr element includes a class "unreaded".  If that is indicating whether the element is unread, then you could do something like this:

```
unread_answers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded")
```

which should give you the list of webelements that are unread.

You can create your loop to go through this list to extract the number from the id by using something like:

```
for unread_row in unread_answers:
    row_id = unread_row.get_attribute("id")
    m = re.search('answer_row_\d*', row_id)
    row_number = m.group(1)
```

(note, my python may be a little rough, and this is all untested, but you should be able to get the idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class name` for element  identification as follow:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(//tr[@class="notifycircle new fnormal abs nowrap br3 cfff lheight16"]')
```